# GTS 450 CUDA Occupancy

Tags: cuda

I have a GTS 450 which has 4 SM's with 48 cores on each SM . ie 192 CUDA cores

Consider I m using limited register memory and shared memory

With compute capability 2.1 , What would be the optimal block size and thread size to achieve 100% occupancy ?

Comment: Use `CUDA_Occupancy_Calculator.xls` included in CUDA SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**download**](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) the appropriate CUDA Toolkit (v5.0) and look for *CUDA Occupancy Calculator* excel sheet, if you haven't already downloaded it. If so you use the document I mention above. It would tell you how to achieve 100% or whatever occupancy you want once you set the initial properties/parameters. One among others is computer capability. Which is also the most important I'd say.